# default settings for webstorm

Tags: settings, default, webstorm

Every time I launch web storm to look at a project it prompts me to switch to ES6 and JSX Harmony.  I'd like the IDE to use these by default.  Is there any way to set these settings as my default in web storm?

Comment: All available default settings can be accessible via `File | Default Settings...` and will affect future new projects only.

Comment: perfect thanks.  if you repost it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All default settings (that got applied to the newly created projects) are accessible via `File | Default Settings...`.

Such settings do not have any effect on already existing/configured projects -- only future new projects.